# Slow Delete Operation in PostgreSQL, no trigger, no foreign key

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

i had a table that contains 51Mils rows, 19GB disk (according to statistics).It does not have any trigger or foreign key. Let's called it table A with index (col1,col2).

My problem is , i had to delete it based on multiple conditions on regular basis (we do this regularly). But it's too slow!

From explain query, i think it is properly indexed (both col order and based on our select needs) as it show only 100ms operation for ~250  **OR** conditions :

```
explain ... delete from table A where
 ( (col1 = 'A' and col2 = '2023-03-04') OR (col1 = 'A' and col2 = '2023-03-05') ..... 250 conditions)
```

Yet the actual query runtime is about 50000ms (500x slower), for 250 conditions, no significant improvement when i chunks it down to 100, etc (250 is already my chunk size from 20K-ish conditions that needed to be cleaned btw)

The autovacuum is running for each day, last i check the dead rows is about ~3Mils.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Show us the plans, rather than trying to summarize them for us.

Answer (score 1):

> ~250 **OR** conditions

That's almost certainly a problem and pretty unreasonable.

> 250 is already my chunk size from 20K-ish condition

20,000 `OR` clauses would definitely be unreasonable.

Your index appears appropriate for the query you're trying to run, but you should re-write your query to be more reasonable which will probably be more performant.

I wouldn't doubt currently your entire table / index is being scanned instead of seeked on, because of your *complex* `WHERE` clause predicate with too many `OR` clauses. You can try re-writing it into a much more simpler query like so, to hopefully elicit an index seek:

```
DELETE FROM table A 
WHERE col1 = 'A'
AND col2 >= '2023-03-04'
AND col2 < '2023-11-05' /* Plug in whichever end date to your range of rows being deleted */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a different solution. Some ideas:

1. write the query like this:

   ```
   WHERE (col1, col2) IN (('A', '2023-03-04'), ('A', '2023-03-05'), ...)
   ```
2. load the value pairs into a temporary table and run

   ```
   DELETE FROM tab
   USING temptab
   WHERE (tab.col1, tab.col2) = (temptab.col1, temptab.col2);
   ```

An index on `(col1,col2)` *might* speed up the statement.